# Forcing language prefix on URL in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'd like to force my site's URL to always have a language suffix.

So, if they type `www.mysite.com` it should take them to `www.mysite.com/en`.

I have a default language, so that should be used if it's their first time to the site.  If it's not, I have a Cookie being set that I can use...but - I don't know where to use it.

I thought about checking to see if there was a "language" parameter in the URL, then if not, redirecting, but - that seems overkill - is there a better way?  Can I do this in routes?  or bootstrap?

Comment: If you want them to be requesting a URL with a language suffix, a redirect is a perfectly appropriate response.  What "overkill" are you trying to remove?

Comment: @BradKoch - if they hit my site via the normal URL, it has to run through the bootstrap, load models, run through logic in the AppController, then reload the page and do it all again, y/n?. Granted, I could put the logic as the first thing in the AppController (probably should), but - dunno - just seemed like something that could be handled by ... routes or something... dunno.

Comment: Understood, Cake side I'm not sure you can do anything other than route to a controller that does the redirect (it's what I've done in the past).  Have you considered using mod_rewrite to do this?

Comment: @BradKoch - the default and available language(s) are editable via an admin tool (ie they're stored in the DB) - so - I'm not sure how I could do it via mod_rewrite.  If I DO put it in a controller, I assume I'd put it in the AppController's beforeFilter()?

Comment: If the languages are in a DB, you're correct, it would need to be in AppController or a Component.  Can't use mod_rewrite or routes when there's no db access yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What I did:**

I ended up checking in the AppController's beforeFilter() whether or not `$this->request->params['langauge']` was set and if not, building the URL accordingly:

```
//Redirect to same url, but with language parameter
if (empty($this->request->params['language']) &&
empty($this->request->params['admin'])) {
    $defaultLanguageCode = Configure::read('Languages.default.code2');
    $cookiedLanguage = $this->Language->activeLanguageByCode($this->Cookie->read('lang'));
    $languageToRedirectTo = (!empty($cookiedLanguage['code2'])) ? cookiedLanguage['code2'] : $defaultLanguageCode;
    $newURL = '/' . $languageToRedirectTo . $this->request->here;
    $this->redirect($newURL);
}
```

**Note:**

The part I couldn't figure out (until getting help in IRC) was to build the URL using `$this->request->here`, which is just the URL as a string.  Prior to that I tried building out the array using the params array, but had no luck.

**My routes (in case they help anyone)**

(Keep in mind, I'm a routes noob, so - although they seem to be working for me, I do NOT guarantee they're done well!)

```
//root URL and root URL w/ language
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));  // eg: www.google.com takes them to pages/display/home
Router::connect('/:language', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'), array('language'=>'[a-z]{2}')); // eg: /en takes them to pages/display/home and sets language

//pages (eg. /en/r/the_matrix  or  /r/the_matrix)
Router::connect('/:language/r/:slug/*', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'display'), array('language'=>'[a-z]{2}', 'pass'=>array('slug')));
Router::connect('/r/:slug/*', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'display'), array('pass'=>array('slug')));

//adds language to default URL
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('language'=>'[a-z]{2}'));

//Route prefixes
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));

//User related
Router::connect('/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/logout', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'));
Router::connect('/myaccount', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'my_account'));

//
CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way would be through your web server. You can easily check if the request is for `/` (the home page) and redirect to `/en`.

Check the docs for what ever web server you are using, they all have something like `mod_rewrite` or similar.

**Edit**

You could set up a route like `/set_default_language` to redirect to in case of `/`, this controller can access the db and do what ever it needs.

Alternatively you can make it redirect to `/your/usual/language_switch` with no language specified and allow the code to use the default.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to redirect the requestAction calls from within your controllers or views you should add the following condition to your IF statement

```
    if (empty($this->request->params['language']) &&
    empty($this->request->params['admin']) && 
    empty($this->request->params['requested'])) {
    ...
    }
```