# Overriding redirect in AppController

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, overriding

I want to override "redirect" to insert a language prefix. For that I've added thist to AppController.php

```
public function redirect( $url, $status = NULL, $exit = true ) {
    die(debug('$url'));
    if (!isset($url['language']) && $this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
        $url['language'] = $this->Session->read('Config.language');
    }
    parent::redirect($url,$status,$exit);
}
```

Obviously the die(..) is just for testing if this function is called.

My controller code:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Party']['language_id'] = $this->Session->read('Config.LanguageId');
        $this->Party->create();
        if ($this->Party->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->write('partyId', $this->Party->id);
            return $this->redirect(array(
                'controller' => 'parties',
                'action' => 'editGuestlist',
            ));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The party could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that "$this->redirect" in XyzController will call my public function "redirect" in AppController.

If I'm adding a party I'm getting redirected to /parties/editGuestlist no prefix is added and the code doesn't stop. So it is prety obvious that my overriding is not working. As I'm new to cakephp I'm hoping that somebody can explain this behavior to me.

**UPDATE**

I've found an error in /config/routes.php that fixed the behavior but I still have no clue why my overriding function isn't called at all.

I've added array('language' => '[a-z]{3}') to

```
    Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*',
        array(),
        array('language' => '[a-z]{3}')
    );
```

Comment: You want to implement internationalization and localization?? see the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897391/forcing-language-prefix-on-url-in-cakephp

Comment: Yes, i18n is the background for this and it's working well. But as I tried to say in my update I'm curious why my wrong route resulted in "skipping" my overriding function. For me, with my limited cake know how, it's really whired.

Comment: Print override `$url` after `if` statement in AppController `die(debug('$url'));`